# Can't see my SKShapeNode when creating a custom class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, invisible, skshapenode

I've been working on a project with quite a lot of nodes, and am finding that I'm having to create an SKNode with an SKShapeNode added as a child to it. But I feel like I should be able to just be able to initialise a custom class of SKShapeNode.

When I do (code below), when I add the class to my GameScene as a child it registers its there (the physics body is there) but the I can't see the shape.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class WallNeut: SKShapeNode {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init(radius: CGFloat) {

        super.init()

        zPosition = 10
        lineWidth = 5
        strokeColor = SKColor.grayColor()

        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
        physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        physicsBody?.pinned = true

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `super.init()` which is the designated initializer but are nowhere defining the path you want your SKSpriteNode to follow.

This can be done in your custom init by adding :

```
path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)), nil)
```

for a circle you may also want to fill it with :

```
fillColor = NSColor.grayColor()
```

Comment: That worked! Glad I didn't try trial and error. Changed "gray" (referencing a different class) thanks.

Comment: If this answers your question you can mark it as 'accepted answer'. This is all the thanks that's needed ;-)